# Font does not work after connecting it to Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, google-fonts

I connect the font in head (index.html)

```
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
```

file tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = { 
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"], 
    theme: {
        extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            playfair: ['"Playfair Display"', 'cursive'],
          }
        }
      }
};
```

and how I use `<h1 class="font-playfair">Enjoy Your Favorite Coffee</h1>`

I checked the font is attached correctly, because if you attach it in the css file everything works

Comment: I've checked in Tailwind play and it seems to work just fine: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9i8HZ5fxIl

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, maybe it's because I installed tailwind using (cdn)?

Comment: I need to have more context to be able to help. So, please share more details on how exactly you set up your project. But it sounds suspicious what you're saying about CND: if you just referenced tailwind in your HTML, `tailwind.config.js` doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and comment about using CND, I assume you might have been mixed two possible setup options in an incorrect way.

### CDN setup

This is the simplest option, it doesn't require dealing with any command, installing node packages, etc. All you need is to add `script` tag to reference `tailwindcss` library from the CDN and, if needed, add any configurations or customization in that same HTML file. See more details in [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn).

Note that in this case, `tailwind` does not have access to other files, it can work only with what included into the HTML code. So configs and everything else should be included explicitly.

This is an example using that font:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            playfair: ['"Playfair Display"', 'cursive'],
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="font-playfair">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### CLI setup

In that case you should use Command-Line Interface (CLI) to build your retulting CSS file based on configuration in `tailwind.config.js` and you input CSS files.

Minimum setup to add that font would be:

1. In the empty folder install `tailwindcss` node package (run `npm i tailwindcss`);
2. Create `tailwind.config.js` with your configuration:

```js
module.exports = { 
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"], 
    theme: {
        extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            playfair: ['Playfair Display', 'cursive'],
          }
        }
      }
};
```

3. Create `src` folder and `index.html` in that folder:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="font-playfair">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Run build by calling `npx tailwindcss -o ./src/output.css` so it will create `output.css` in the `src` folder.

Whenever you change configuration, or add more CSS, you'll have to rebuild `output.css` to reflect changes. You can also run build command adding  `--watch` argument, so it will monitor your files changes and automatically rebuild the `output.css`.

See more details in [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).